# Facebook chat in iPhone app with push notifications

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook, push-notification

We're planning an app which, among other things, is supposed to integrate a facebook chat.

We're discussing about the push notifications for receiving messages while the app's in background. What comes to mind is a proxy server for the chat, that'd actually connect to the facebook chat, and the iPhone app would connect to the proxy.
Then, it's easy to have the proxy server act as a push notification server.

Is this the only way to go, or are we making this more complex than it needs to be?

Any input is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

To do push notification (App is closed, user receive a message and an alert appear on the iPhone), that's the only way, because every app need an unique certificate to send push notifications. This mean that official Facebook servers can't push for third-party applications. You need a proxy that keep a connection open to FB and push alerts to Apple's Push Notification Server when needed.

Inside the app, instead, you can connect directly by opening a socket to Facebook's servers and use a Jabber library for ObjC. This allows another approach: Local Notifications. They're similar to Push, but they doesn't need a proxy server: it's the application running on user's device that keep an open connection (even when the app is in background) with Chat Server.

This is the documentation that covers both type of notification: [Local and Push Notification Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Comment: The question is: will the socket keep the connection and keep receiving data while in the background?

Answer (score 0):

Facebook's chat system is a Jabber server, so I think you are making it more complex than you need to.

Comment: So, how would you implement push notifications if you don't use a proxy server?

Comment: Take this with a grain of salt, I'm speaking with no experience in the specific area. The reason why I'm thinking it's over complicated is that jabber is a well known protocol, so I imagine there is a library you can use to interface to it. I'm not sure push notifications are needed, but like I said, I'm not an expert. MrMagic's answer is probably more useful.